# Detect end of vertical scroll in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` where I insert multiple items inside it, so that the `ScrollBar` position changes, depending on the items I get from an endpoint.

That controls added to panel are added into a `foreach` statement like:

```
foreach (var test in testList)
{
  //Multiple Combobox, panels etc. created programatically
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control1);
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control2);
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control3);
}
FormatPanel(tableLayoutPanel);
```

Also I format my panel as:

```
 private void FormatPanel(TableLayoutPanel panel)
        {
            TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles = panel.RowStyles;
            foreach (RowStyle style in styles)
            {
                style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
                style.Height = 50;
            }
        panel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        panel.AutoScroll = false;
        panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
        panel.AutoScroll = true;
    }
```

I want to know how can I detect if the `ScrollBar` position is at the ground and fire an event?

How can achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I try to use constructor right after `InitializeComponent()`

```
  tableLayoutPanel.Scroll +=  (s, e) => {
                HandleScroll();
            };
```

Then I create `HandleScroll` method:

```
  private void HandleScroll()
        {
            var maxVerticalScroll = tableLayoutPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

            if (tableLayoutPanel.VerticalScroll.Value == maxVerticalScroll)
            {
                var a = "";
            }

        }
```

But for some reason maxvalue is higher than the end of my scroll, why that happen?

Comment: Usually you have to subtract the thumbsize from the scroll maximum to get the range.

Comment: How can I access to thumbsize from scroll? @LarsTech